# Use @SentTo to send a message with Spring Boot and RabbitMq

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Is it possible to send a return value of any method to a queue using an annotation, like

```
@SentTo("my.queue.name")
String send() {
    return myString;
}
```

Do I definitely need a @RabbitListener to use @SendTo? Maybe another way out?

I'm trying to simplify my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@SendTo` is only currently for replies from a `@RabbitListener` where the sender didn't set a `replyTo` header.

You could do what you want with a [Spring Integration `@Publisher` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#publisher-annotation) with its channel wired to a rabbitmq outbound channel adapter...

```
@Publisher(channel = "amqpOutboundChannel")
public String send() {
    return myString;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "amqpOutboundChannel")
public AmqpOutboundEndpoint amqpOutbound(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
    AmqpOutboundEndpoint outbound = new AmqpOutboundEndpoint(amqpTemplate);
    outbound.setRoutingKey("my.queue.name"); // default exchange - route to queue 'my.queue.name'
    return outbound;
}
```

The method has to be public and invoked from outside the bean itself.